# Sql select statement with two conditions in visual basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve Two Columns; App_ID & App_Slot from a table `su_Appointments` from an sql server database using vb, and I have two conditions the Date and Time; App_Date & App_Time for the query, now when I run the query it throws an error saying : Incorrect syntax near '2014'. The query is as follows
I am going to store App_ID into the variable AP_ID

**CODE**

```
 Using Query As New SqlCommand("Select App_ID From su_Appointments Where (App_Date = ' and  App_Time = ' )" & DT & TM, sqlcon)
   sqlcon.Open()
   Dim dr As SqlDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader()
   While dr.Read()
   AP_ID = dr(0)
   End While
End Using
sqlcon.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your syntax is effectively wrong

A SELECT statement requires

```
SELECT <fieldA>, <FieldB>, .... 
FROM <Table> 
WHERE <FieldX> = <Condition1> AND <FieldZ> = <Condition2>
```

But, a part from this basic error, you need to start using a parameterized query approach

```
Using sqlcon = new SqlConnection(.....connectionstring...)
    Dim cmdText = "Select App_ID From su_Appointments Where App_Date =@dt and App_Time = @tm" 
    Using Query = New SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlcon)
       sqlcon.Open()
       Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DT)
       Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tm", TM)
       Using dr =Query.ExecuteReader()
           While dr.Read()
             AP_ID = dr(0)
           End While
       End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

With a parameterized query, you get many benefits. There is no possibility of [Sql Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work), the text of your command is more clear and understandable, the parameters are treated for correct quoting by the code itself so you don't need to check for single quotes inside your strings, or format correctly dates and  decimal numbers.

Eventually, you could encounter a different problem. If your columns `App_Date` and `App_Time` are of type datetime then you need to pass parameters of the appropriate type, not simply strings. Instead if, these fields are of type `nvarchar` (or some other kind of text type) then you pass strings but you will have problems storing and querying correctly in these fields.

Comment: Thanks alot Steve it works very well, and I find the parameterized approach alot more controllable. Thank you so much again bro!